# Sending an adaptive card to openrainbow message chat

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-sns, azure-data-lake

I am trying to send a message to openrainbow using this script but it's giving me an html in the message chat of openraibow messsage

```
`import os
import json
import boto3


def envoyer_message_sns(ticket_card):
    sns_client = boto3.client("sns")

    topic_arn = os.getenv("SNS_RAINBOW_GATEWAY_TOPIC", "arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:146034197703:rambow-gateway-notification")
    subject = os.getenv("POWERTOOLS_SERVICE_NAME", "Notification")

    payload = {
        "Message": json.dumps(ticket_card),
        "Recipients": {
            "bubble": [],
            "userLogin": [
                "user@gmail.com"
            ]
        }
    }
    sns_client.publish(
        TopicArn=topic_arn,
        Message=json.dumps(payload),
        Subject=subject
    )


ticket_card = {
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Lambdas errors in last 24 hours",
            "size": "large",
            "weight": "bolder"
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "sfdc-synchronizer-production-PrepareMaterial: (10 / 55055) < 1 % :"
        }
    ],
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.Submit",
            "title": "Création des tickets",
            "data": {
                "action": "createTicket"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Action.Submit",
            "title": "Commencer l'analyse",
            "data": {
                "action": "startAnalysis"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

envoyer_message_sns(ticket_card)`
here when I send the request what it gave me :
[image]
here is what I am expecting :
[image: here is the expected result]